# Update a HTML in a Panel passing some parameters (Ext Js)

Tags: javascript, extjs

As the title says I want to update a HTML into a Panel passing some parameters to it.
An example of the code I am using is:

```
Ext.getCmp(panelId).load(
    {url:'htmlInThePanel.html',
     scripts:true,
     params:{
          par1 : x,
          par2 : y
         }
     }
);
```

I learnt about this on this web:

http://www.learnsomethings.com/2010/08/23/loading-an-external-page-into-an-extjs-panel-and-allowing-the-page-to-execute-script/

And the problem I have is that I do not know how to access the params inside the html.
Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Thank you for your answer but I still have the problem, maybe I did not understand what you mean, this is what I have tried:

```
params:{
    par1 : "Test text"
}
```

and into the html:

```
<span id="par1">
</span>
```

I expected to have the "Test text" where I have put the span, but it does not work, I also tried with the same result:

```
<span id="params.par1">
</span>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You just want to load `htmlInThePanel.html` in your page? If so .. you don't need params.

Comment: I need to load that htmlInThePanel.html into the panel, giving to it a list of parameters and accessing their values inside the html, for showing them as content of the html.

Answer (score 0):

I guess those parameters should be wrapped into span/paragraphs/divs with id's like:

```
<span id="par1">par1_value</span>
<span id="par2">par2_value</span>
```

and your code could be

```
params:{
    par1 : Ext.get('par1'),
    par2 : Ext.get('par2')
}
```

Comment: I cannot do that, The main post is all about the Question, here is the Answer.

Comment: Did you read the main post before the edit? Here is not the answer to:

"And the problem I have is that I do not know how to access the params inside the html. Any idea?"

Comment: This is what I understood: You want to load `htmlInThePanel.html` into your page, but also send some variables in the AJAX call.

Comment: But is it possible to get the values of an AJAX call into the HTML?

Comment: And using scripts into the HTML?

Comment: Yes in javascript you can modify, it depends on what you have on that HTML, you can modify it's contents directly with `load`'s `callback` function, I believe it has that function ..

Comment: But the callback function will be called after showing the html into the panel, so my parameters will not be showed into the html's content... will they?

Comment: Okey, I give up, thanks for trying, I will not use .html files used like templates, I will try to generate the html somehow with everything configured.

Comment: the HTML modifying in the callback is immediately, so your parameters can be inserted in that HTML